# cloth simulation messes up

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation, pose-mode

I make a character with 2 skirts.  The skirts has cloth simulation on.  When I make the character spin around, the inner skirt is fine, but the outer skirt collapses and get stuck on itself.  Please see the picture.

What are the possible causes?

Any possible way to fix this?
[image]

Thank you,

Comment: Enable Self Collisions?

Comment: yes did with 4 step quality and .1cm margin.

Comment: Even with one cloth collision it can be very tricky. It is better to post simplified blend https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: I dont know if this is the right place to mention this.  If not, then I apologize in advance.  I heard there are cases where the scene or object or both in a file went bad... and it is better to export object or scene to new file.  Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever that's happened to me it's usually because there is an outdated bake on that mesh. Delete the bake and then Bake All Dynamics.

Comment: i delete and bake all many times... still not fixed.

Comment: Even cache deleted I remember it is still somewhere. You can try delete and change some parametric to really get cache overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest turning on Self Collision via the Collisions section.  This way, the cloth won't intersect itself. I have a feeling that Oliver was right and that you need to bake everything again.  If that doesn't work, try toggling Self Collision.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vVoQ-1U0SY - This is for 2.8 but it's still relevant.  Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).